# How to loop through all items in the grid when paging property for grid is set

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, grid, pagination

I have grid where i am setting the page size as 14 ,and my grid contains 56 items, when i trying to loop through the grid items it considers only the first page 14 items and comes out of the loop, but i want rest of the items also , please can any one help me to solve this problem.

```
if (AvailableRolesGrid.Items.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (GridDataItem availablerole in AvailableRolesGrid.Items)
                    {
                       //

}
}
```

Comment: Are you using GridTableView? You can try ItemsHierarchy instead of Items. But performance-wise, you are better off hitting the DataSource instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use the DataSource, like this:

```
DataTable table = (DataTable)DataGrid1.DataSource;
if (table != null)
{
     foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
     {
          string roleName = row.Field<string>("RoleName");
     }
}
```

This is probably better actually, because it will be easier to access the data. Doing it through the grid, you'll have to pull the values from the cells, which would be a pain.

Comment: @mahesh: My code was just an example. Cast the DataSource to whatever type it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding to the grid, why not use the dataset or datatable you binded to the grid and loop through it.  It has all the recordsets that were returned from your datasource.  Since it is binded to your grid whatever changes you make to it will reflect in the grid.